# How to set a size-limited queue that holds last N elements in Dart, Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, queue

I am creating an app with Flutter, I need to display real time data coming from a json file into a dynamic chart.

the data I am displaying is a value that's changing every 10 seconds. So I am creating a chart in which I wanna show the last 5 values(y axes) in the last 50 seconds(x axes).
I did fetch the json file successfully and displayed the dynamic data using a timer in a text widget.

My issue is how to store the last 5 values(of the last 50seconds) and showcase them all in the dynamic chart.
I thought of creating a queue in which I store the value and display it periodically but it only shows one value; as I couldn't set the queue size to 5 elements.

This is the [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y664k.png) I am getting, each 10 seconds it displays a real time value but, I need it to be variable curve( value of now and the value of 10 seconds ago and of 20seconds ago... on each point).

Is there any way I can define a constant size of the queue?
Or are there any other solutions to this issue?

Any help is much appreciated, Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
Future<Donnee> fetchDonnee() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('url'));
  //url not shown for confidentiality 
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response, then parse the JSON.
    return Donnee.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));  
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response, then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class MyApp2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp2> {
  late TooltipBehavior _tooltipBehavior;
  late Future<Donnee> futureDonnee;
Timer? timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tooltipBehavior = TooltipBehavior(enable: true);
    print('initstate');
    futureDonnee=fetchDonnee();
    super.initState();
    //every 10 seconds json is fetched and values are extracted
    timer= Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds:10), (Timer t){
      futureDonnee=fetchDonnee();
      setState(() { });
      }
    );
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('builder');
    FutureBuilder f1;
         Center(  
          child: 
          f1=FutureBuilder<Donnee>( 
            future: futureDonnee,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                  //function func return value just stored in the queue
                  Text((func(snapshot.data!.w1))),
                  SfCartesianChart(
                    primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
                    title: ChartTitle(text: 'Puissance active de la phase 1'),
                    legend: Legend(isVisible: true),
                    tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,

                    series: <LineSeries<PowerData, String>>[
                      LineSeries<PowerData, String>(
                        dataSource:  <PowerData>[
                        PowerData('10', double.parse(func(snapshot.data!.w1))),
                        PowerData('20', double.parse(func(snapshot.data!.w1))),
                        PowerData('30', double.parse(func(snapshot.data!.w1))),
                        PowerData('40', double.parse(func(snapshot.data!.w1))),
                        PowerData('50', double.parse(func(snapshot.data!.w1)))
                        ],
                      xValueMapper: (PowerData power, _) => power.seconds,
                      yValueMapper: (PowerData power, _) => power.power,
                      dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true)
                      )
                    ]
                  )
                ],);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return 
                  Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          )
         );
      return f1;      
  }
}

//class for the chart
class PowerData {
  PowerData(this.seconds, this.power);
  final String seconds;
  final double power;
}

function to store the values in a queue and return the recent value
String func(valr){ 
  Queue queue = new Queue();
   queue.add(valr);
   print(valr);
   print(queue);
   return valr;   
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want something like [`package:circular_buffer`](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_buffer)?

Comment: *"Is there any way I can define a constant size of the queue? "* with simple `Queue` you can use `add` method (and `removeFirst` if after adding the `Queue`'s size exceeds your limit)

Comment: @pskink , The problem is that I have a timer that reinitiates the build every 10seconds so if I write queue.add('whatever') 4 times and queue.add(value) 1 time to create a queue of 5 elements. the values are not shifted and it keeps on initiating the build and displaying this (whatever whatever whatever whatever (value : 555 for example)), so only the last item which is value is changing with no shifting.

Comment: @rooroo Huh?  Instead of calling `queue.add('...')` directly, you could have a helper function: `void addToQueue<E>(Queue<E> queue, E item) { queue.add(item); if (queue.length > 5) { queue.removeFirst(); } } `.  It wouldn't matter how many times you call it or whether it's called form a `Timer`.

Comment: And if your problem is that you're creating a *new* `Queue` all the time, then just stop doing that.  Use a single, shared `Queue`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I just implemented the addToQueue function but it's still showing me only the last value, the length of the queue is still equal to 1

Comment: @jamesdlin I created a function to create the queue of five values all equal to '1' in another file. and called the queue here in a function that contains addToQueue and now I am getting in the debug console a queue of 5 elements ( 1 1 1 1 1 "changing value")

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing.  If you're still using the same code as you've originally posted, your `func` function creates a new `Queue` object every time it's called, and you call it multiple times.  Otherwise I'd need to see your updated code.

Comment: how do I make it not create a new object every few seconds?

Comment: @jamesdlin Is there any way i can call the timer without having queue being affected by it

Comment: Is there any other way I can display a dynamic value fetched from json in a chart please(y axes)

Comment: "how do I make it not create a new object every few seconds?" Why can't you create and store a `Queue` object somewhere else (e.g. `_MyAppState`, perhaps) and reuse that?